# Cached Thread Pool in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, threadpool

My application uses `Spring 3.0.5 Release`.  I have collection with 10000+ entities. As per my business requirement I need to traverse each property and bind to a pojo in get another collection. The  function/process is handled by single request/thread.

I came accross `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ConcurrentTaskExecutor`. I tried implementing it.

But compared to normal process latency it takes 2 fold of time.Think it is not reusing the thread. Each and every time its spawn a new thread consumes resource.

So How can I implement cached thread pool of Java concurrency via Spring Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [source code of that class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/3.0.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ConcurrentTaskExecutor.java/#82) tells us it **defaults** to using `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())`, so you're right in your assessment. However, the Javadocs tell us there's [a constructor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ConcurrentTaskExecutor.html#ConcurrentTaskExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor%29) that lets you pass in any JDK executor you wish. Also, the summary for that class tells us Spring has a [`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) that lets you configure a `ThreadPoolExecutor` as a bean.